# Extracting groups of characters that match a pattern from a string in VB

Tags: regex, vb.net, string, parsing

I'm still a regex baby and need some help parsing a string.

I am using VB, and intend to run a string through NCalc, a library that parses mathematical equations from strings.

The problem is, the equations will have numbers, operations *and* variables.

An equation may look like this:

```
P20*4.143/((N2+N3)/2)
```

As you can see, P20, N2 and N3 are variables. In my case, they are stored in a datatable elsewhere in my application.

What I need to do is parse the string, looking for *groups* of characters in-between operations (-+/*), get their *actual* values and replace the variable with the value in the original string all while ignoring actual numbers.

The above string should become:

```
120.5*4.143/((4500+4570)/2)
```

So something like this:

```
Dim equation = "P20*4.143/((N2+N3)/2)"

For Each match As String In Regex(match_all_groups_with_letters)
    return replace(match, value)
Next
```

Then I can do something like:

```
finalResult = NCalc.Doyourmagic(equation)
```

Comment: You can match all vars with [`"\b\p{L}+\d*\b"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cp%7bL%7d%2b%5cd*%5cb&i=P20*4.143%2f((N2%2bN3)%2f2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simple pattern like

```
"\b\d*\p{L}[\p{L}\d]*\b"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cd*%5cp%7bL%7d%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cd%5d*%5cb&i=P20*4.143%2f((N2%2bN3)%2f2)+%2f+6P20)

It matches a leading word boundary `\b`, zero or more digits (`\d*`), a letter (`\p{L}`), and zero or more digits or letters (`[\p{L}\d]*`) followed with a trailing word boundary (`\b`).

Adjust the quantifiers accordingly (if the digits are always present, use `\d+` instead of `\d*`). If the letters can only be ASCII letters, use `[A-Za-z]` (or just uppercase ASCII - `[A-Z]`) instead of `\p{L}` (that matches all Unicode letters).

Comment: My fault for not specifying that variable names could start with either letters on numbers, but always contain letters. Is there a way to modify it to include variables such as "6P20"?

Comment: It is not difficult. `\b\d*\p{L}[\p{L}\d]*\b`

Comment: It may not be difficult for you, but that is chinese for me! Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: I explained (I hope) well. Actually, the other suggestion by Olivier is one of the possible alternatives (I described how you can build a similar one from mine in my answer). If you need to *replace* later, do it with `Regex.Replace` at once, do not collect matches with `Regex.Matches` (unless you need them for something else). Leverage a match evaluator.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that variable names always start with a letter and may contain numbers

```
Dim equation = "P20*4.143/((N2+N3)/2)"
Dim pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*" ' Can start and end with numbers,
                                                 ' must contain at least one letter.

Dim matches = Regex.Matches(equation, pattern)
For Each m As Match In matches
    Dim value = GetValueFor(m.Value)
    equation = Regex.Replace(equation, "\b" & m.Value & "\b", value)
Next
```

`\b` marks the beginning or end of a word. The square braces `[]` enclose character groups. The star `*` means zero, one or more repetitions of the preceding operation. So we have any number of repetitions of letters and digits, then exactly one letter, and finally again any number of repetitions of letters and digits.

---

Instead of re-using Regex for replacing the identifiers found, you could use the information provided in the match. It has `Index` and `Length` properties telling you the exact location of the identifiers in the equation. You can then replace by using string functions. But make sure to iterate the matches the reverse way in order to preserve the positions of the not yet processed identifiers.

---

You will have to somehow get the values corresponding to identifiers. A `Dictionary(Of String, Double)` is ideal for holding the values. The key is the identifier.

Comment: My fault for not specifying that variable names could start with either letters on numbers, but always contain letters.

Comment: Why do you match and then replace when you can replace without checking for matches? That involves redundant overhead.

Comment: Because you will have to replace the different matches (different identifiers) by different values. How do you want to specify these different values? (e.g. P20 = 77, N2 = 8.32, N3 = 0.22)